# CSS design for 3 column list

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

Given a large dynamically growing list of things in alphabetical order, I want to have them all listed in 3 columns.  For example:

[image]

Is there any way in CSS to have 3 equal height columns for lists like these where the count of items in each heading are not known?

A fluid column display where I don't need to program a way to calculate how many should be in each column etc.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think there's a forum here for web designers, you have more chances of finding good answers there.

Comment: I pressume you want one list to spread across 3 columns right? Well, I don´t think its actually possible. You need to use either div or span tags to create these columns, and your list cant actually flow from one div or span to another. Talking about CSS2 of course...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need CSS3 rules from [this web page](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm after.  Am I correct in saying IE doesn't support these at all though?

Answer (score 0):

You can download [blueprint css](http://www.blueprintcss.org/).  You have to learn about it a bit before it becomes helpful but it's worth it.